# How to program i2c eeprom by hand?

Tags: eeprom

I have a 24c02 eeprom and I want to program it. But I don't have Arduino or any microcontroler. I saw a video about program eeprom by hand, but they are parallel eeprom. This is the link of that video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BA12Z7gQ4P0
I am very sorry that english isn't my mother language. Sorry about any mistake
Thank you very much

Comment: This is not something you can realistically do.  Get an MCU or dedicated USB/I2C bridge or hack a connection to an extra video card's EDID (I2C) lines or something like that.

Comment: What you want to do is not realistic.   You'd have to implement the i2c data and clock lines with toggle switches.  Every 8 clocks transfer a byte. transfer a byte.  Then you'd have to key in i2c protocol to load address and data.  Miss 1 bit and you'd have to start over.  Not a good idea.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!

Comment: I have done this sort of thing in the past, using a PC parallel port and custom cable plus software. But you want to do I2C, which you can just get a USB dongle for or use any MCU you have laying around. That is way easier.